# Is there any way to create python-like generators in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, iterator, generator

In python if you loop over (or consume) an

1. iterator
2. function return value

you do not even know which one you have. So it does not matter from the caller side if you have returned or yielded values from the callee to use in caller.

However, as far as I know in javascript if you want to use yield, you have to explicitly mark the function* with an asterisk and can not treat the computed value the same way as a "regular function's return value" on the caller side.

Is there an abstraction in javascript to hide these differences to get the same nice abstraction which python has?

Comment: @Jony-Y: Your link broke; the parser doesn't consider `*` part of the link. [This one should go where you wanted it to.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: Not sure why the JS generator syntax bothers you though... You have the solution on how to do it. do you just not want to use the generator syntax?

Comment: @user2357112 thanks. after reading the question I saw that he knows what generators are in JS. Im trying to understand whats the problem with them or is it just the sugarcoating that bothers him

Comment: What makes you think you can't treat a generator the same way as any other iterable a function might return?

Comment: For the second question ("can not treat the computed value the same way"): there are several constructs that work just as well on arrays as on iterators, as the iterator of the array is used in that case. For example: `for (let x of f())`. `f` can be a generator or a plain function that returns an iterable such as an array.

Comment: @trincot Okay thanks! This `for (let x of f())` seems good for me. Is there any appellation/concept what is happening here? Or how do I find "all the standard possible ways" to do that in js?

Comment: @trincot what if in both cases I want to assign the xs to new Array? In case of generator its ok to step over the values one by one, but if I have an Array as is I don't want to step over one by one on it again. In python I could have just `list( f() )`.

Comment: In JS that would be `Array.from(f())` or `[...f()]`. Read about iterables and iterators (note the difference) [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). It has examples, syntaxes, ... etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several constructs in JavaScript where the caller does not need to know whether the called function is a generator, or a plain function that returns an array, string, Map, ...etc. These return values all have in common that they are iterable.

Here are two examples on how you can treat the return value of such a function:

1. Iterate through the values:

   ```
   for (let x of f()) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Depending on what `f()` returns, `x` will be the following:

   - Iterate a string: get each character
   - Iterate an array: get each element of it
   - Iterate a Map: get each key/value pair of it
   - Iterate an iterator (maybe returned by a generator): get each yielded value  from it
   - ...
2. Create an array from the values:

   ```
   const copy = Array.from(f());
   ```

   Or also:

   ```
   const copy = [...f()];
   ```

   NB: the nice thing of `Array.from` is that it accepts a callback function as a second argument: a mapper called for each value.
3. Spread the values as arguments to another function

   If the values are numerical:

   ```
   Math.min(...f());
   ```

   As `Math.min` can accept multiple arguments (not just two), this gives the minimum value of the whole series (as `min` does in Python).

Read more about iterators and iterables [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Answer (score 0):

**SINCE ES6**:

There is [a new "generator" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), which works **almost exactly** like generators in Python. From MDN:

```
function* generator(i) {
  yield i;
  yield i + 10;
}

const gen = generator(10);

console.log(gen.next().value);
// expected output: 10

console.log(gen.next().value);
// expected output: 20
```